# Power Query/Excel: Error with DateTime.ToText()

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, powerquery

In Excel 2016 - Query Editor - Advanced Editor.

Here is my code:

```
let
    SettingsSheet = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"TimeRange" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SettingsSheet,{{"From", type datetime}, {"To", type datetime}}),
    From = #"TimeRange"[From],
    To = #"TimeRange"[To],
    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd-THH:mm:ssZ",
    FormattedFrom = DateTime.ToText(#"TimeRange"[From], DateFormatString ),
    FormattedTo = DateTime.ToText(To, DateFormatString ),
    ...
    (Further in the code, I will need to concart formatted datetimes in a URL string.)
```

If I finish with

```
...
in
   #"TimeRange"
```

I get a table with DateTimes, as expected.

If I finish with
    ...
    #"testTable" = { From, To, FormattedFrom, FormattedFrom}
    in
       #"testTable"

I get a table displaying
1 List
2 List
3 Error
4 Error

while I expected
3 and 4 to be date formatted as `DateFormatString` suggests.

I have also tried without `DateFormatString` as in

```
FormattedFrom = DateTime.ToText(#"TimeRange"[From]),
```

and with `DateFormatString = "YYYYMMDD",` as shown in example on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253497.aspx
But I got the same result.

How am I supposed to format dates ?

> Edit: Error says: Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type
>   List to type DateTime. Details:
>       Value=List
>       Type=Type

Comment: By clicking right from "error" in the cell the error-message will be shown in the preview-window. It is often helpful to copy this into your thread as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime.FromText expects a cell as a first argument instead of a column.

This added custom column would create a textstring that concatenates the 2 Dates with the desired format and "-" as a separator:

```
   String = Table.AddColumn(#"TimeRange", "String", each DateTime.ToText([From], DateFormatString)&"-"&DateTime.ToText([To], DateFormatString))
```

Comment: It says "Expression.SyntaxError: Token Equal expected." after "Table.AddColumn(" .Also, I really need this in a string variable, I mean I need to build a URL to call a data service afterwards. Do I get that string this way then MyString = #"TimeRange"[String]   (I'm not familiar with this language at all.)

Comment: Check out this code: let
    SettingsSheet = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"TimeRange" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SettingsSheet,{{"From", type datetime}, {"To", type datetime}}), DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd-THH:mm:ssZ",
    
String = Table.AddColumn(#"TimeRange", "String", each DateTime.ToText([From], DateFormatString)&"-"&DateTime.ToText([To], DateFormatString)) in String

Comment: If you want to learn more about this language, start with this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299038.aspx and the surrounding articles & check out for more here: http://www.thebiccountant.com/learning-resources/

Comment: I'm one step further now.

Now the problem is, when I write "url = "http://myurl/something/?from=" & FormattedFrom[FromDate] & "&to=" & FormattedTo[ToDate], Source = OData.Feed(url)," I get
"Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List. Details: Operator=&" Left= [left side of url] Right=List"

Comment: One step further, I need to use "FormattedFrom[FromDate]{0}"

Comment: semicolon doesn't seem to belong in here: "url = "myurl/something/?from="; &  instead: "url = "myurl/something/?from=" &  ...Apart from that you should be fine now?

Comment: Meanwhile I solved it. I check the answer but I think if you edit it so that it doesn't generate "Token Equal expected.". May be clearer if somebody has use for it.